# delayMIcroseconds and micros execution time not explainable

Tags: timing

i just experimented with the timing accuracy of my Arduino Uno R3 using this code:

```
unsigned long beginTime;
unsigned long endTime;


void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600); // open a serial port
}

void loop() {
  beginTime = micros();
  delayMicroseconds(200);
  endTime = micros();
  delay(500);
  Serial.println(endTime-beginTime);
  delay(500);
}
```

The results I got are (just an excerpt):

```
200
204
200
200
204
204
204
200
212
208
212
204
204
```

I tried to understand this behavior, read this link [Can I make delayMicroseconds more accurate?](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/37387/can-i-make-delaymicroseconds-more-accurate).

Due to the timing of `micros` (4 µs) I would understand values between 200 and 208. **But why do I get occasional values of 212 microseconds?** I'm kinda curious, since I bought the Arduino because of bare-metal programming and bounded execution times.

Comment: Maybe you good some interrupts running during your measurement occasionally. That would make the actual execution time longer.

Comment: try to add Serial.flush() to wait until Serial finishes

Comment: @Juraj: Thanks for the suggestion. I tried it (i.e. added a `Serial.flush();` after the `println`, but it did not work.

Comment: @chrisl: Thanks, I added `noInterrupts();` before the first `micros();` and `interrupts();` after `endTime = micros();`. I got consistend values, either 200 or 204 microseconds, which was expected :). 
Do you know, which interrupts might be triggered  while running such a simple program?  I thought, `Serial.flush();` might stop any possible interrupt, but that was not the case..

Comment: The Arduino core uses a timer interrupt for timekeeping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Arduino core uses hardware Timer0 with its ISR (Interrupt Service Routine) for timekeeping. While `delayMicroseconds()` directly uses the value of the hardware timer, `delay()` and `millis()` are handled by the ISR. It will be called regularly.

If the ISR is getting executed during your measurement, then the execution time of the ISR will add to the execution time of your measured code. Thus you get a higher count occasionally.

To prevent this you can either deactivate all interrupts (via `noInterrupts()`) or deactivate this specific interrupt, either by stopping Timer0:

```
TCCR0B &= ~( (1 << CS02) | (1 << CS01) | (1 << CS00) );
```

or by letting the timer run, but deactivating its interrupts:

```
TIMSK0 = 0;
```

For details about this have a look at the [datasheet of the Atmega328p](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/Atmel-7810-Automotive-Microcontrollers-ATmega328P_Datasheet.pdf), which is the microcontroller on the Arduino Uno.